# Graphviz not displaying PNG in Python Idle

Tags: ipython, graphviz, python-idle, digraphs

I am using the following code to display in image in Python IDLE but no luck.

```
import pydot
import graphviz
import os

G = pydot.Dot(graph_type = 'digraph')
node = pydot.Node('Name')
G.add_node(node)
from IPython.display import Image, display
im = Image(G.create_png())
display(im)
```

Each time I run the code, it returns the following instead of displaying a png.

```
<IPython.core.display.Image object>
```

Could someone point out whats wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: It seems that display is printing the string representation of the object.  Running this code from IDLE's editor should have no effect.  But to be sure, run it directly with python from a command line: `python <path.to/file.py>`.  And report here.  If you get the same ouput, `python-idle` tag should be removed.  If you see an image, please use @ to direct a comment to me.  Also, what python version, and OS?

Comment: Hey Terry!
So I used the aboved code in jupyter and it displayed the image.
I am fairly new in python so I wasn't aware of Jupyters functionality.
But thanks for your response!